# cruisecontrol.net issue - lastbuildstatus and lastbuildtime shows invalid information

Tags: dashboard, cruisecontrol.net

I'm facing two issues with ccnet:

1. two builds executed at the same time for the same project, which is totally invalid and one build failed with exception and another build passed. and another issue occurring because of this is the last build status is shown as Failure which is not correct as the last build passed.
2. sometimes ccnet dashboard shows last build status and time of previous build and not of the latest build. this also leads to other problems.

if we can find how last build status and time is shown to dashboard then we may find the root cause of it.

please advise

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to see how CCNet can trigger 2 builds of the same project at the same time on 1 buildserver. If it was a superfast computer, and the project does 'nothing' (only a nulltask or so) maybe one can simulate this. Because of the timestamp used on the build artifacts. Can you post the involving part of ccnet.config of those projects?